# Timeout a Jenkins job and rebuild

Tags: jenkins

I tried to use the [Build-timeout](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build-timeout+Plugin) Plugin to timeout a job at deadline but couldn't figure out how to correctly setup the timeout action with "Abort and restart the build".

If I choose the Time-out strategy to be "Deadline", there will be a field called "Deadline tolerance in minutes":

> Deadline tolerance in minutes:
>
> Period in minutes after the deadline time when a job should be immediately aborted. E.g. if deadline is defined as "13:50", tolerance as "5" minutes and job is scheduled to run at "13:52" it will be immediately aborted. However if it is scheduled at "13:56", job's deadline will be set at "13:50" of next day.

By default it was 1 minute and **cannot be set to 0**.

My problem is, if I set the Time-out action to be "Abort and restart the build", it will restart the build **immediately** on timeout and then obviously the restarted build will always fall into the tolerance window so it will always be aborted immediately.

How can I setup the deadline correctly so that it just simply aborts the job and restarts it without any tolerance feature?